# Enumeration of footnotes wrong

Tags: tables, numbering, footnotes

I have a small table, where I need a footnote and after it a text with another footnote.
So I researched for it and found out, that I shall use `\footnotemark` in combination with `\footnotetext` in the table.

But what shall I use after the table?

I have tried `\footnotemark` and `\footnote`, but always the enumeration in the footnotes list is wrong. In the text stands for example 1 and 2 and in the list of footnotes 2 and 2.

Also I tried to give numbers, but **I don't want to enumerate** all footnotes on myself.
Furthermore I set following options `plainpages=false, hyperfootnotes=false` for `hyperref`, because I get warnings like

```
name{Hfootnote.2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist
```

and

```
destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again>  \chapter
```

I used for the table the `tabular`.

Comment: Have a look on [Is there a reliable footnote command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/is-there-a-reliable-footnote-command) and tell us if it helps.

Comment: See also the [UK TeX FAQ: Footnotes in tables](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=footintab).

Comment: Without a minimal example it's difficult to know what sort of advice would help you...

Comment: @Martin Thanks, but I don't get it running. See my edit above.

Comment: @Seamus Minimal example is online.

Comment: Some of the information over here might be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/footnote-to-a-footnote

Answer (score 6):

Try this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{A text footnote.}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Me\footnotemark & Myself & And I\footnotemark
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotetext{A table footnote.}
\addtocounter{footnote}{+1}\footnotetext{Another table footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{Another text footnote.}

\end{document}
```

i.e. before the first footnotetext place a  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1} (if there are more footnotemarks in the table, you will need -2, -3,...) and then increase it for each following footnotetext with +1.

This does **not** correct the hyperlinks to the footnotes!

To do this automatically (including the hyperlinks):

- `\usepackage{tablefootnote}` in the preamble (if [rotating](http://CTAN.org/pkg/rotating) package is used: `tablefootnote` after `rotating`) and `\tablefootnote{text of the footnote}` in the table. [tablefootnote](http://CTAN.org/pkg/tablefootnote)

From the "Alternatives" section of the tablefootnote-package:

> - The longtable package provides the longtable environment as replacement for
>     the combined table and tabular environments. Footnotes are real footnotes
>     (not just tablenotes), are continuously numbered and hyperlinked (when
>     using the hyperref package), and the hyperlinks really work. As drawback the
>     appearance of the caption changes slightly (e. g. distance to the table, width
>     of the caption), which can probably be changed back manually. Furthermore,
>     longtables are meaned to break over more than one page. If that is not
>     wished, it must be prevented by \nopagebreak-commands and by ending
>     the longtable lines with \* instead of \. longtables do not 
>     oat. (Therefore using the tablefootnote package and \FloatBarrier from the picins package
>     before and after the table environment is similar - but tablefootnote does not
>     change the table-caption!) sidewaystable does not work with it.
>     http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable
> - The supertabular package provides the mpsupertabular environment as replace-
>     ment for the combined table and tabular environments. Footnotes are
>     just tablenotes (with working hyperlinks when using the hyperref package),
>     i. e. numbered a, b, c and placed below the table and not at the end of the
>     page. Therefore there is no float problem (because the tablenotes number-
>     ing is not included in the continouse numbering of the footnotes). Placing
>     the supertabular inside of a sidewaystable breaks the hyperlinks to the
>     tablenotes.
>     http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular
> - The ctable package has its very own notation for dening tables. It can create
>     tablenotes and sideways-tables. The tablenotes are not automatically hyper-
>     linked. The ctables float. Because the tablenotes numbering is not included
>     in the continouse numbering of the footnotes there is no float problem.
>     http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable
> - The footnote package provides \makesavenoteenv{table}. After loading the
>     package and using that command in the preamble, in tables \footnote{...}
>     can be used. Using \makesavenoteenv{tabular} and
>     \makesavenoteenv{sidewaystable} is possible, but it neither solves the float problem, nor do the created hyperlinks work (i. e. they aim at wrong locations). The mdwtab from the same bundle is incompatible with other table-related packages (e. g. supertabular, array) and not 100% compatible with the tabular environment.
>     http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnote
>     http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdwtab
> - The tabularx package does produce footnotes for sidewaystables, but uses a, b,
>     c instead of 1, 2, 3. The hyperlinks to the footnotes do not work. Because
>     the footnotes numbering is not included in the continouse numbering of the
>     other footnotes there is no float problem.
>     http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
> - Placing a tabular inside a minipage inside a table produces tablenotes. There-
>     fore there is no float problem (because the footnotes are not continousely
>     numbered). The hyperlinks to the table notes indeed work.
> - The threeparttable package creates tablenotes again. Therefore there is no float
>     problem (because the tablenotes are not continousely numbered with the
>     footnotes). There are no hyperlinks to the table notes (at least not auto-
>     matically). Using sidewaystable (with table notes) works.
>     http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable
> - The threeparttablex package creates tablenotes again. Therefore there is no 
>     float problem (because the tablenotes are not continousely numbered with the
>     footnotes). With option referable the tablenotes are hyperlinked. Use of
>     a sidewaystable (with table notes) did not work for me. When using the
>     referable option according to the example in the threeparttablex manual
>     the longtable package is used, therefore that package could be used directly
>     without threeparttablex (see above). http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex

Comment: Yes it works, but it seems pedestrian. I have a lot of tables with footnotes. Isn't there any package which do that for us?

Comment: @H3llGhost: Please see edited answer for automatically accomplishing this. There are packages to do this indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Martin Scharrer already pointed you to the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footintab). Here's one way to add footnotes in tables (emphasis added):

> Use `\footnotemark` to position the little marker appropriately, and
> then put in `\footnotetext` commands to fill in the text *once you’ve
> closed the `tabular` environment*.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{A text footnote.}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Me & Myself & And I\footnotemark
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\footnotetext{A table footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{Another text footnote.}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that I used the wrong order after the tabular. But the enumeration is also wrong if you used more than one `footnotemark` and depending on it more `footnotetext`. In the list both footnotes get the same number. I have tried to give numbers manually, but they disturb the counter.

Answer (score 1):

As the FAQ points out: tables and footnotes don't work well. Use a `minipage` as advised or rethink your approach to tables.