# Footnote in environment as parallel (2nd part)

Tags: footnotes, minipage, parallel

I refer to this tread: [Footnote in environment as parallel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171154/footnote-in-environment-as-parallel#). If I build a little more complex environment to enlarge the text width in two columns quotation, there is a trouble with notes number. Please, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature=-clig,Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Contextuals=NoAlternate}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{EB Garamond}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{GFS Didot}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=1cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\linespread{1.10}
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{verse}
\setlength{\vleftskip}{15pt}

\usepackage{parallel}
\newlength\leftwidth
\newlength\rightwidth
\newenvironment{verseparallel}[2]
{\begin{Parallel}{0.44\textwidth}{0.54\textwidth}\footnotesize\parindent=0pt
\ParallelLText{\leavevmode #1}\ParallelRText{#2}}
{\end{Parallel}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{verseparallel}{\medskip}
\AfterEndEnvironment{verseparallel}{\medskip}

\usepackage[perpage,bottom,hang,stable,norule]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{2em}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{0.00001pt}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\hspace{1em}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Costellazioni antiche}
La maggior parte delle ottantotto costellazioni è di origine greca. Gli antichi 
in esse vedevano delle figure reali e, spesso, le associavano a personaggi 
mitologici. Tra le più antiche vi sono quelle dello zodiaco.

\section{Costellazioni dello Zodiaco}
Le dodici costellazioni zodiacali sono quelle che fanno da sfondo al moto del 
sole nel corso dell'anno, se parliamo in termini tolemaici, al moto apparente 
del sole, se parliamo in termini copernicani. Le possiamo vedere prima 
dell'alba, subito dopo il tramonto e in caso di eclissi.

L'Ariete è una delle costellazioni dello zodiaco; si trova tra i Pesci a ovest e 
il Toro a est ed è una figura caratteristica dei cieli autunnali boreali. Si 
tratta di una costellazione di dimensioni relativamente contenute. Le sue stelle 
sono tuttavia abbastanza luminose. L'Ariete si individua con facilità poco a 
ovest delle Pleiadi e a nord della grande costellazione della Balena. La 
costellazione diventa visibile nel cielo serale alla fine dell'estate boreale 
(settembre) e resta visibile per tutto l'autunno e l'inverno, fino al mese di 
marzo; dall'emisfero australe invece la sua visibilità è più limitata, anche a 
causa dell'incremento delle ore di luce nei mesi compresi fra ottobre e 
dicembre, ossia in quei mesi di massima visibilità nel cielo serale\footnote{bla bla bla}.

In astronomia, l'Ariete ha molta importanza poiché ai tempi dei Greci conteneva 
il punto cardinale noto come equinozio di primavera, il punto γ. È il punto in 
cui vi è l'intersezione tra l'eclittica e l'Equatore e in cui il giorno 
dell'equinozio di primavera si formano tre croci come scrive
Dante\footnote{D\textsc{ante}, \emph{Paradiso}, \textsc{i}, 37-42}:

\begin{verse}
Surge ai mortali per diverse foci\\
la lucerna del mondo; ma da quella\\
che quattro cerchi giugne con tre croci,

con miglior corso e con migliore stella\\
esce congiunta, e la mondana cera\\
più a suo modo tempera e suggella.
\end{verse}

Ma l'equinozio di primavera non è fisso, a causa della lenta oscillazione 
dell'asse terrestre nota come precessione\footnote{bla bla bla}.

Quando, intorno al 130 a.C., il grande astronomo greco Ipparco definì la 
posizione dell'equinozio di primavera, questo punto si trovava a sud della 
stella Mesarthim (Gamma dell'Ariete). Fu allora fissato qui l'inizio dello 
zodiaco, e quindi l'equinozio di primavera fu comunemente noto come il primo 
punto dell'Ariete. A causa della precessione, l'equinozio di primavera si è 
spostato di circa 30 gradi dai tempi di Ipparco e attualmente si trova nella 
confinante costellazione dei Pesci. Ciò nonostante, esso viene ancora chiamato 
il primo punto dell'Ariete\footnote{bla bla bla}.

La costellazione dell'Ariete è per lo più associata al mito del vello d'oro, 
ripreso in parte da Apollonio Rodio nella saga delle \emph{Argonautiche}.

Secondo il mito l'Ariete comparve sulla Terra quando il Re Atamante di Beozia si 
accinse a sacrificare suo figlio Frisso per allontanare una carestia incombente. 
Il re Atamante, infatti, si era unito a Ino, figlia del Re Cadmo della vicina 
Tebe. Ino, però aveva in odio i figliastri, Frisso ed Elle, avuti da Atamante 
con la prima moglie Negale, e organizzò una cospirazione per farli uccidere. 
Cominciò a bruciare il grano per evitare che ci fosse un raccolto. Quando 
Atamante chiese aiuto all'Oracolo di Delo, Ino corruppe i messaggeri affinché 
ritornassero con la risposta falsa che Frisso doveva essere sacrificato per 
salvare il raccolto.

A malincuore, Atamante portò suo figlio in cima al Monte Lafisto, che sovrastava 
il suo palazzo a Orcomeno. Era sul punto di sacrificare Frisso a Zeus quando 
Nefele intervenne per salvare suo figlio, mandando giù dal cielo un ariete alato 
dal vello d'oro. Frisso si arrampicò sul dorso dell'animale, dove fu raggiunto 
da sua sorella Elle che temeva per la propria vita. Volarono via in direzione 
est verso la Colchide, che si trovava sulla sponda orientale del Mar Nero, sotto 
le Montagne del Caucaso. Lungo il percorso Elle non riuscì a mantenere la presa 
e cadde nel canale fra l'Europa e l'Asia, i Dardanelli, che in suo ricordo i 
Greci chiamarono Ellesponto. Una volta raggiunta la Colchide, Frisso sacrificò 
l'ariete a Zeus in segno di gratitudine. Regalò il suo vello d'oro al terribile 
Re della Colchide, Eeta, che, in cambio, gli concesse la mano di sua figlia 
Calciope.

Dopo la morte di Frisso il suo fantasma ritornò in Grecia per perseguitare suo 
cugino Pelia, che si era impadronito del trono di Iolco in Tessaglia. Il vero 
successore a quel trono era Giasone. Pelia promise di lasciarglielo se gli 
avesse portato dalla Colchide il vello d'oro. Fu questa la sfida che diede il 
via all'epico viaggio di Giasone e degli Argonauti.%\footnote{bla bla}

Al suo arrivo in Colchide Giasone chiese al re Eeta di dargli il vello che 
pendeva da una quercia in un bosco sacro, custodito da un enorme serpente sempre 
sveglio.

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{minipage}{1.1\textwidth}
\begin{verseparallel}
{\begin{greek}%
τὸν δ᾽ Ἄργος προσέειπεν ἀμηχανέων κακότητι:\\
‘Αἰολίδην Φρίξον τιν᾽ ἀφ᾽ Ἑλλάδος Αἶαν ἱκέσθαι\\
ἀτρεκέως δοκέω που ἀκούετε καὶ πάρος αὐτοί,\\
Φρίξον, ὅτις πτολίεθρον ἀνήλυθεν Αἰήταο,\\
κριοῦ ἐπεμβεβαώς, τόν ῥα χρύσειον ἔθηκεν\\
Ἑρμείας: κῶας δὲ καὶ εἰσέτι νῦν κεν ἴδοισθε.\\
τὸν μὲν ἔπειτ᾽ ἔρρεξεν ἑῇς ὑποθημοσύνῃσιν\\
Φυξίῳ ἐκ πάντων Κρονίδῃ Διί. καί μιν ἔδεκτο\end{greek}}
{Vi era già prima noto, credo, che Frisso, nipote di Eolo,\\
venne ad Eete della Grecia; Frisso che giunse alla città di Eete,\\
cavalcando un montone che fu mutato da Ermes in oro,\\
e il vello potete ancora oggi vederlo\\
disteso sui folti rami di una quercia; poi,\\
come il montone stesso chiese,\\
lo sacrificò a Zeus, il figlio di Cronos,\\
nella sua veste di protettore di esuli\footnotemark.}
\end{verseparallel}
\end{minipage}}\footnotetext{A\textsc{pollonio} R\textsc{odio}, \emph{Argonautiche},
\textsc{ii} 1140-1146.}

\end{document}
```

You'll realize that option `perpage` doesn't seem to work here (on page 3, the only footnote has number 4); on the contrary, if you put a `\footnote` in the third page before the note put "manually" with `\footnotemark` and  `\footnotetext`, all works fine. I think there is something wrong or bad working because of minipage...

Comment: Myriad Pro is not a monowidth font...

Comment: Yes, changed to `\setsansfont`, even if that is not the main problem