# Footnotes in pages environment using the parallel package

Tags: footnotes, parallel

Following up on [Footnote in environment as parallel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171154/footnote-in-environment-as-parallel), I am trying to typeset footnotes using the `parallel` package but with the `[p]` (Pages) environment, which prints the parallel texts on facing pages.

I would like each footnote to appear on the **same page** as the footnote mark.

However, using `\footnote{}` places the footnote after the `parallel` environment ends (as the documentation warns), which turns out to be the top of  the **following** page.

Using a `\footnotetext{}` after the parallel texts but still within the `parallel` environment places the footnote in the footer of the **preceding** page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{parallel}
\newenvironment{verseparallel}[2]
{\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}
\ParallelLText{#1}\ParallelRText{#2}}
{\end{Parallel}}

\begin{document}
\begin{verseparallel}
{To be, or not to be\footnote{(A) footnote appears on next page}}
{To be, or not to be\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{(B) footnote appears on preceding page}
\end{verseparallel}

\end{document}
```

In either case, the footnote is printed on a different page than the footnote mark. Is there a workaround to place a footnote at the bottom of the same page as the footnote mark?

Comment: `paracol` package may be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired output of typesetting footnotes for parallel texts, following the suggestion to use the `paracol` package instead.

For the configuration that best matches `parallel` package with the `[p]` option for multiple pages, consult the `paracol` documentation section 9.2, "Non-Paired Parallel-Paging". Example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\newenvironment{verseparacol}[2]
{\begin{paracol}[1]*{2} % two columns, one per page, non-paired
#1\switchcolumn#2
}{\end{paracol}}

\begin{document}

~ \clearpage % clearing the page so the first column starts on verso

\begin{verseparacol}
{To be, or not to be\footnote{(A) footnote}}
{To be, or not to be}
\end{verseparacol}

\end{document}
```