# Real footnote with subcaption package

Tags: captions, footnotes, subcaption

I'd like to put some footnotes in a caption of a `subcaption` paragraph. However, as you can see the footnode appears in the caption itself, and not at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Any solution?

Thanks!

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% To display subfigures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{My caption with a footnote\footnote{Yes I like footnotes ! But this one is not a true foot note, because it's not at the bottom of the page...}}
    \label{fig:myfiga}
  \end{subfigure}\hspace*{.05\textwidth}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Other caption}
    \label{fig:myfigb}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{My big caption}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since a subfigure is basically a minipage, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274/can-i-get-a-normal-footnote-in-a-minipage-environment-in-latex-how?s=4|54.0991  However, since you don't know what page you will wind up on (despite the h!) you may have problems putting it at the bottom of the page.  The bottom of the figure would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` pair:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% To display subfigures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{My caption with a footnote\protect\footnotemark}
    \label{fig:myfiga}
  \end{subfigure}\hspace*{.05\textwidth}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Other caption}
    \label{fig:myfigb}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{My big caption}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Yes I like footnotes ! But this one is not a true foot note, because it's not at the bottom of the page...}
\end{document}
```

Or, if you prefer a more automatic solution (requires LaTeX 2020-10-01, at least), you can redefine `\footnote` in the `figure` environment, so that it does `\footnotemark`, and store the `\footnotetext` in a hook to be executed after the `figure` environment, then you can just use `\footnote` inside `figure`:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% To display subfigures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\footnote[1]{%
    \footnotemark
    \expanded{\AddToHookNext{env/figure/after}%
      {\noexpand\setcounter{footnote}{\thefootnote}%
       \noexpand\footnotetext\unexpanded{{#1}}}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{My caption with a footnote\footnote
      {Yes I like footnotes ! But this one is not a true foot note,
        because it's not at the bottom of the page...}}
    \label{fig:myfiga}
  \end{subfigure}\hspace*{.05\textwidth}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Other caption\footnote{Another}}
    \label{fig:myfigb}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{My big caption\footnote{MOAR}}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any option to reduce the [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Procedural_programming) of this approach? I have defined each subfigure in its own file and placing the `\footnotemark` and the `\footnotetext` in different files sounds confusing to me.

Comment: @ChristophThiede I added a solution that doesn't require separating the text from the footnotemark

Comment: My latex compiler does not know `\AddToHook` (undefined control sequence), is this some miktex specific thing?

Comment: @ChristophThiede No, you need to update your distribution.  You need at least TeX Live 2020.  Try this instead (didn't check throughly though): `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\atendfigurenotes{}
\AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\atendfigurenotes\let\atendfigurenotes\@empty}%
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\DeclareRobustCommand\footnote[1]{\footnotemark\xdef\atendfigurenotes{\unexpanded\expandafter{\atendfigurenotes}\noexpand\setcounter{footnote}{\thefootnote}\noexpand\footnotetext\unexpanded{{#1}}}}}`

Comment: Sigh, installed texlive 2021 but `\AddToHook` is still not found ... I also tried your other alternative (assuming the `%` should not be part of the string) but footnotes still appear in the figure.

Comment: @ChristophThiede Something's wrong then, in TeX Live 2021 `\AddToHook` should already be there.  What does `latex '\stop'` show on the terminal?

Comment: `latex '\stop'` and `pdflatex '\stop'` shows *TeX Live 2021*, but the Latex Workshop extension for VS Code still uses the old version, I don't know why. I have filed an issue here: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/2868

Comment: @ChristophThiede Ah, so it seems VS Code is not using the right path to TL 2021.  I don't use VS Code, so I can't help you further, sorry.

Comment: Yahoo, I finally got it working! :-) / I needed to change `env/figure` to `env/figure*` as I use a full-page figure in a two-column document, maybe that's worth a note. / It's just a pity that your approach seems not to work for figures that are displayed on the next page, but [this seems to be a general issue with footnotes and figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181/221054).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had a similar use case but I wanted to display all footnotes spawned from a subfigure right below the parent figure. To achieve this, I have adjusted [Phelype's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414191/221054) from above (requires LaTeX 2020-10-01 or higher):

```
\usepackage{footmisc}
\AddToHook{env/subfigure/begin}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand\footnote[1]{%
        \mpfootnotemark
        \expanded{\AddToHookNext{env/subfigure/after}%
            {\noexpand\setcounter{mpfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}%
             \noexpand\footnotetext\unexpanded{{#1}}}}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% To display subfigures
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\AddToHook{env/subfigure/begin}{%
\DeclareRobustCommand\footnote1{%
\mpfootnotemark
\expanded{\AddToHookNext{env/subfigure/after}%
{\noexpand\setcounter{mpfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}%
\noexpand\footnotetext\unexpanded{{#1}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Other caption}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace*{.05\textwidth}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.47\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption[LoF entry]{My caption with a footnote\footnote{This footnote is displayed right below the subfigure at the bottom of the containing parent figure.}}
\end{subfigure}
        \caption{My big caption.}
        \label{fig:usage_mining/patterns}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]